# android JUnit Tests not running

Tags: java, android, junit

The problem is not that the tests are failing, but that they simply do not run at all.
That is to say, the console tells me they run, but I see absolutely no results from them at all.

Note that I 'have' remembered to annotate methods with @Test

Here's the code for the test class:

```
package module.jakway.JournalEntry.test;


import module.jakway.JournalEntry.Module_JournalEntry;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MainTest extends android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Module_JournalEntry>
{

    public MainTest(Class activityClass) {
        super("module.jakway.JournalEntry", Module_JournalEntry.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        Module_JournalEntry journalentry = getActivity();

        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void myTestCase()
    {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

}
```

The project I'm testing is named Module_JournalEntry with package module.jakway.JournalEntry and Activity Module_JournalEntry.java

Here's the console output:

```
[2011-02-04 20:37:10 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2011-02-04 20:37:10 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'my2.3Emulator'
[2011-02-04 20:37:12 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-02-04 20:37:12 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Project dependency found, installing: Module_JournalEntry
[2011-02-04 20:37:14 - Module_JournalEntry] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-02-04 20:37:14 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
[2011-02-04 20:37:14 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Collecting test information
[2011-02-04 20:37:17 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2011-02-04 20:37:17 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Running tests...
[2011-02-04 20:37:19 - Module_JournalEntryTest] Test run finished
```

and the logcat output:

```
02-04 20:37:10.266: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(524): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-04 20:37:10.266: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(524): CheckJNI is ON
02-04 20:37:11.236: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(524): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-04 20:37:11.316: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(524): Shutting down VM
02-04 20:37:11.336: INFO/AndroidRuntime(524): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-04 20:37:11.346: DEBUG/dalvikvm(524): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 3ms+8ms
02-04 20:37:11.346: DEBUG/jdwp(524): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-04 20:37:11.346: DEBUG/dalvikvm(524): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-04 20:37:12.316: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(534): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-04 20:37:12.316: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(534): CheckJNI is ON
02-04 20:37:13.136: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(534): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-04 20:37:13.186: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(534): Shutting down VM
02-04 20:37:13.216: INFO/AndroidRuntime(534): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-04 20:37:13.216: DEBUG/dalvikvm(534): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
02-04 20:37:13.216: DEBUG/dalvikvm(534): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-04 20:37:14.256: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(544): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-04 20:37:14.256: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(544): CheckJNI is ON
02-04 20:37:15.126: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(544): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-04 20:37:15.176: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Force stopping package module.jakway.JournalEntry uid=10035
02-04 20:37:15.206: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Start proc module.jakway.JournalEntry for added application module.jakway.JournalEntry: pid=552 uid=10035 gids={1015}
02-04 20:37:15.876: WARN/TestGrouping(552): Invalid Package: '' could not be found or has no tests
02-04 20:37:15.976: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Force stopping package module.jakway.JournalEntry uid=10035
02-04 20:37:15.976: INFO/Process(75): Sending signal. PID: 552 SIG: 9
02-04 20:37:15.986: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(544): Shutting down VM
02-04 20:37:16.016: DEBUG/dalvikvm(544): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 71% free 299K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+4ms
02-04 20:37:16.036: INFO/AndroidRuntime(544): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-04 20:37:16.046: DEBUG/jdwp(544): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-04 20:37:16.046: DEBUG/dalvikvm(544): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-04 20:37:16.656: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(563): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-04 20:37:16.665: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(563): CheckJNI is ON
02-04 20:37:17.646: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(563): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-04 20:37:17.716: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Force stopping package module.jakway.JournalEntry uid=10035
02-04 20:37:17.746: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Start proc module.jakway.JournalEntry for added application module.jakway.JournalEntry: pid=572 uid=10035 gids={1015}
02-04 20:37:18.606: WARN/TestGrouping(572): Invalid Package: '' could not be found or has no tests
02-04 20:37:18.826: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Force stopping package module.jakway.JournalEntry uid=10035
02-04 20:37:18.826: INFO/Process(75): Sending signal. PID: 572 SIG: 9
02-04 20:37:18.846: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(563): Shutting down VM
02-04 20:37:18.906: INFO/AndroidRuntime(563): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #4' failed
02-04 20:37:18.916: DEBUG/dalvikvm(563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 71% free 298K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+28ms
02-04 20:37:18.916: DEBUG/jdwp(563): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-04 20:37:18.926: DEBUG/dalvikvm(563): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Android bases its testing framework on JUnit 3 which doesn't use annotations but reflection and test method names should include the **test** prefix.

Move to JUnit 3 and run your tests from Eclipse as `Run As -> Android JUnit Test` or using `am instrument` from command line.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing this:

```
public MainTest(Class activityClass) {
    super("module.jakway.JournalEntry", Module_JournalEntry.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

To this:

```
public MainTest() {
    super("module.jakway.JournalEntry", Module_JournalEntry.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

The constructor should have no parameters in this case. It's written in the [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html) tutorial example under the *Adding the test case constructor* section.

Answer (score 4):

"The Android testing API supports JUnit 3 code style, but not JUnit 4" - http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

1.Update your test to follow JUnit 3 standards

```
    //has to start with the word "test" for JUnit 3 to pick it up.
    public void testMyCase()
    {
      assertTrue(false);
    }
```

2.Remove any JUnit 4 references from the test project (right click project -> properties -> java build path -> Libraries (tab)